# How to access fastify instance from a handler/controller file?

Tags: handler, fastify

I need to access the fastify instance from a handler file. I don't remember at all how I should be doing that.

index:

```
fastify.register(require('./routes/auth'), {
  prefix: '/auth'
})
```

routes/auth:

```
module.exports = function(fastify, opts, next) {
  const authHandler = require('../handlers/auth')
  fastify.get('/', authHandler.getRoot)
  next()
}
```

handler/auth:

```
module.exports = {
  getRoot: (request, reply) {
    // ACCESS FASTIFY NAMESPACE HERE
    reply.code(204).send({
      type: 'warning',
      message: 'No content'
    })
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routes/auth:

```js
module.exports = function(fastify, opts, next) {
  const authHandler = require('../handlers/auth')(fastify)
  fastify.get('/', authHandler.getRoot)
  next()
}
```

handler/auth:

```js
module.exports = function (fastify) {
  getRoot: (request, reply) {
    fastify;
    reply.code(204).send({
      type: 'warning',
      message: 'No content'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: My savior! <3 Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

fastify.decorateRequest('fastify', fastify); Will now return a warning message:

```
FastifyDeprecation: You are decorating Request/Reply with a reference type. This reference is shared amongst all requests. Use onRequest hook instead. Property: fastify
```

Here is the updated usage for the OnRequest hook for requests:

```
fastify.decorateRequest('fastify', null)    
fastify.addHook("onRequest", async (req) => {
        req.fastify = fastify;
});
```

Replace "onRequest" with "onReply" if needed for replies.
[See Fastify docs on it here.](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Decorators/)

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**
you can use `this` keyword for accessing fastify instance in your controllers that are defined with `function` keyword. Arrow function controllers won't work.

You can also decorate fastify instance on request or reply object:

`index`:

```
fastify.decorateRequest('fastify', fastify);
// or
fastify.decorateReply('fastify', fastify);

fastify.register(require('./routes/auth'), {
  prefix: '/auth'
});
```

Then in your `handler/auth`:

```
module.exports = {
  getRoot: (request, reply) {
    // ACCESS FASTIFY NAMESPACE HERE
    request.fastify
    // or
    reply.fastify

    reply.code(204).send({
      type: 'warning',
      message: 'No content'
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a simpler way to access `FastifyInstance`, without creating a function wrapper (Closure) or fastify decorators:

```js
fastify.get('/', function handler (req, _) { req.server; })
```

In the above code, `req.server` points to the `FastifyInstance`.
The only difference with the above instance is that it's scoped to the current route context, as discussed in the referenced doc.

Ref: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Request

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Fastify instance from `request.server` see also: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Request/

So in your example:

```js
getRoot: (request, reply) {
  // Fastify instance
  console.log(request.server)
}
```

This has been added since PR: https://github.com/fastify/fastify/pull/3102